# asp classic: Application "home" url

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic

Im working on a new company, and they have a classic asp application.
Nobody knows how to configure it, so im having a bad time.

The problem is that when the code calls something like that:
`<img src="/images/TesteiraHome.png" />`

on a URL like: `http://localhost/myApplication/index.asp`

the IIS tries to get the IMG from the URL: `http://localhost/images/TesteiraHome.png`

How can i set the "base" url for my application, so the iis will try to catch the image from `http://localhost/myApplication/images/TesteiraHome.png`

Thanks

EDIT:
I dont wanna refactor all the project. Isn't there any IIS configuration to make it understand that / means locahost/myapp/ ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

Add a new site on IIS and put the physical path.

Choose it to run on any unused port (for me 8090)

And now it understands that this is the default route.

Answer (score 0):

well, sticking with HTML you can use the [`<base>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/base):

```
<base href="http://localhost/myApplication/" />
```

However, it's probably better to specify the image to `runat="server"` and use `~/images/TesteiraHome.png` as the location. Alternatively, you can use [`ResolveUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx) or [`ResolveClientUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx):

```
<img src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/images/TesteiraHome.png")%>" />
```

And have ASP do it for you.

Comment: I dont wanna refactor all the project. Isn't there any IIS configuration to make it understand that / means locahost/myapp/ ??

Comment: Sadly, in the good old days of ASP classic 'runat=server' and 'ResolveUrl' are just things you dream about...

Comment: @ted: It can be [emulated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7972602/298053) though (kinda). ;p

Comment: Ooh, that looks a bit nicer than the horrible old SITE_URL constant that was littered through our old classic asp sites!

Answer (score -1):

Has it worked successfully in the past? If it has, and it's now been moved to a new server, make sure the site is set up in IIS in the same way as it was originally, i.e. whether it is set as a site, or a virtual directory / application under the default site.

By the looks of it, it should be set up as a site itself, so that the root of the site will be its own directory, rather than wwwroot.

Another, horribly hacky possibility (to avoid any refactoring) would be to simply move the images folder from the site into the root of the wwwroot directory. Not really advisable if you've got any other sites running there though.